# How to make border blink/flash when it is visited by an anchor link in ASP.NET HTML?

Tags: c#, html

So i have a table and items inside it. I have put a link to individual items to direct the user to what the item means

```
@if (fileDetail.ExistsBothFolder == true & fileDetail.IsContentSame == true & fileDetail.IsDateModifiedSame == true)
                        {
                            <td style="background-color: lightgreen">
                                <a href="#Section1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fileDetail.Name)</a>
                            </td>
                            matchingFiles++;
                        }
```

It is in razor in a HTML file
It links to this

```
<a name="Section1"></a><p class ="lead" style="border: 1px solid lightgreen;"><br />&nbsp;This file exists in both directories!<br /> <br />
&nbsp;<img alt="ListView" src="@Url.Content("https://s12.postimg.org/pt4egzh7x/green.png")" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" /> = Matching file <br /> &nbsp;
```

Its a little messy but the link leads to a paragraph which has a border around it, since it is next to other borders i need this one to blink so the user knows which one they are looking at.

Any help thanks

Or the background can be filled for 1 second than reverted once the user sees it. Or the text colour can blink for 1 second. Some suggestions?